# Popup LOV disable through simple Dynamic Action works in Apex 4.2 but not in Apex 19.1

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-19.1

We are migrating applications from Apex 4.2 to Apex 19.1, where we found that Popup LOV is not getting disabled based on value in another field. And that simple Dynamic action works in Apex 4.2

As this is migration project I do not have to change the look and feel of application, but I wonder how it worked in Apex 4.2.

DA1: Disable Popup LOV when page loads
DA2: Change of Item P7_A, when it is not null, Enable Popup else Disable Popup.

Dynamic action fails to enable Popup LOV, although it works with any other Items like Select List, Text field. I tried the same in another theme of APEX19DEV also but it is same. I think it works with Apex4.2 default theme.

There are two items in Popup LOV, one is Text field and another is button which opens another small screen to select vales. In Apex19.1 button doesn’t enable after disabling it on simple Dynamic action which works in Apex4.2.

Comment: Consider editing your question to describe the problem that you are trying to resolve.

Comment: Dynamic action fails to enable Popup LOV, although it works with any other Items like Select List, Text field. I tried the same in another theme of APEX19DEV also but it is same. I think it works with Apex4.2 default theme.

There are two items in Popup LOV, one is Text field and another is button which opens another small screen to select vales. In Apex19.1 button doesn’t enable after disabling it on simple Dynamic action which works in Apex4.2.

Comment: That's good to describe the problem with a comment. I'd prefer that added to the question; but, that's good enough for +1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From javascript hide arrow button to disable the pop up LOV, it worked in above described case rather than disabling it.